# Can a function and its derivative have different input variables?

Tags: graphing-functions

[image]

The problem above is from Khan Academy. The correct answer is "C" and I know how to get it. This is what I have trouble with:

Whenever I see a function and its derivative, both the function and its derivative use the same input variable. For example $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ both use $x$. In the Khan Academy problem, the function is called $f(x)$ so the derivative should be called $f'(x)$. But, since the answer is C, it is impossible for the derivative to be called $f'(x)$ because $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{sin(x)-sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$. In other words, you can only write the derivative as $f'($any variable other than $x)$. So, if the function and its derivative in this problem have different input variables, how can you graph them on the same coordinate plane? I think this issue has more to do with how to graph stuff than calculus.

Comment: The reason that $f'(\pi/2)$ is written is that we are looking at the value of the derivative ($f'(x)$) *at $x = \pi/2$*. There's nothing wrong with writing $f'(x)$ in general, it refers to $\lim\limits_{u\to x}\dfrac{f(u) - f(x)}{u-x}$.

Comment: Because $f'(\frac{\pi}{2})=\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{sin(x)-sin(\frac{\pi}{2})}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$ the derivative cannot have the input $x$. Im not really concerned with the derivative being $f'(x)$ my focus is on the fact that in this Khan Academy problem, it's impossible to say both the function and its derivative have the same input variable.

Comment: Is the reason you think the input cannot be $x$ because there is already an $x$ in the limit you wrote? If so, note that that $x$ is just a **dummy variable** for the limit, it could be written with any other symbol too, e.g. $f'(\pi/2) = \lim\limits_{u\to \pi/2} \dfrac{f(u) - f(\pi/2)}{u-\pi/2}$. When we write $f'(x)$, the $x$ here is different to the $x$ in the limit you wrote earlier. In that limit, $x$ was just a dummy variable of the limit, whereas in $f'(x)$, $x$ refers to the point we are evaluating the derivative at, and $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{u\to x}\dfrac{f(u) - f(x)}{u-x}$.

Comment: Yes because the $x$ in the limit stands for a coordinate of an arbitrary point that gets infinitely close to $(\frac{\pi}{2}, sin(\frac{\pi}{2}))$ while the input of the derivative stands for a coordinate of the point that we want to find the slope at.

Comment: Isn't $f(u)$ still the function?

Comment: Is $f(u)$ or $f(x)$ the original function?

Comment: What term represents the original function in your last limit equation?

Comment: The $f'(x)=\lim_{u\to x}\frac{f(u)-f(x)}{u-x}$ equation

Comment: $f(u)$ is "the (original) function evaluated at $u$". $f(x)$ is "the (original) function evaluated at $x$". For example, for the question you posted, $f(u) = \sin u$ and $f(x) = \sin x$.

Comment: Oh so f(x) is not actually the function. Rather it is the function evaluated at x?

Comment: $f$ is the function

Comment: Yes. Something like $\sin{x}$ refers to a function (the sine function here) evaluated at $x$.

Comment: I know this sounds really basic but why do graphs have an x-axis then? Isn't that implying you can only graph one value, which is $x$, on that graph?

Comment: You can think of the $x$ as a "variable", allowed to take on arbitrary numerical values. So the graph plots what happens as $x$ varies. If we write something like $f'(x) = \cos{x}$, it means "the derivative of $f$ at any $x$ is the cosine of $x$". So for example, the derivative of $f$ at $x = \pi/4$ would be $\cos(\pi/4)$, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. The derivative of $f$ at $x = 1.2$ would be $\cos(1.2)$. And so on.

Comment: Wait so if I graph a function called $f(x)$ and then I graph its derivative $f'(z)$ should the horizontal axis be called the x, z axis ?

Comment: If you are graphing $y = g(z)$, then you may want to label the horizontal axis as "$z$". It doesn't change the shape of the graph if the actual function $g$ is the same though. It's just a label essentially.

Comment: I'm still confused about what allows someone to graph any 2 functions on the same coordinate plane. I think that's my question essentially, I don't even have to talk about derivatives actually.

Comment: Like what requirements are there for when you write out your 2 functions in function notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always think of a function as being a conceptual machine that accepts some type of input (specified as its domain) and produces some output. We write "$f : S → T$" to denote that $f$ is a function with domain $S$ such that when you give it any input in $S$ it produces an output in $T$. We write "$f(x)$" to denote the output of $f$ when applied to input $x$.
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

Now to define a function you **must** specify both its domain as well as its rule for what input yields what output. For example, we could define a function $g$ with domain $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $g(k) = k^2 - 3·k$ for every $k∈\mathbb{Z}$. Observe that the variable "$k$" here is solely used to define the input-output rule; it does not make any difference if we used any other variable such as "$x$" or "$h$".

Many teachers and textbooks are sloppy in defining functions. For instance, your quoted question from Khan academy appears to define function $f$ by the input-output rule $f(x) = \sin(x)$, but failed to specify its domain, so it is technically an incorrect question. However, we can guess that it wants $f$ to have domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Take any function $f : D → \mathbb{C}$ where $D⊆\mathbb{C}$. We define **pointwise differentiability** as follows:

> Given any $x∈D$, we say that $f$ is **differentiable at** $x$ iff $\lim_{y→x}^{y∈D} \lfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ exists (in $\mathbb{C}$).

Then we define the **derivative** of $f$, denoted by "$f'$", as follows:

> $\boldsymbol{f'}$ is the function with domain $E = \{ x : \text{$x∈D$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x$} \}$ such that $f'(x) = \lim_{y→x}^{y∈D} \lfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$ for every $x∈E$.

Again observe that the variables $x,y,E$" in the above definitions are solely used within the definitions, and we could have substituted them for any three distinct variables.

The whole point is that it is **incorrect** to say that a function uses an input variable, but it is not your fault because many people teach the concepts wrongly. Rather, you need to use a variable when specifying the input-output rule in defining a function, but that variable is not in any way tied to the function itself. In fact, such variables are called **dummy variables**, as they only serve to link their occurrences, and do not have meaning outside of the definition.

As to the question in your comments, you have to distinguish between the function and its graph, which unfortunately is another frequent conflation by teachers. Given a function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$, the **graph** of $f$ is defined as the set of points $\{ (x,f(x)) : x∈\mathbb{R} \}$, and you can plot the **graph** of the equation "$y = f(x)$" on the $(x,y)$-plane in the manner you have encountered. You can of course plot the graphs of more than one equation, such as the graph of "$y = f(x)$" and "$y = f'(x)$" on the same $(x,y)$-plane. Note that the choice of variables matters; if you plot the graph of "$x = f(y)$" on the $(x,y)$-plane, you will get a different plot from the graph of $y = f(x)$".

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about the derivative incorrectly.

$f^\prime(a) = \displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. When this limit exist and is finite, we say the function is differentiable at a. So the x value in the limit as approaching the input value $a$.

Comment: In the equation you typed out, how can $f'(a)$ have the input $a$ and $f(x)$ have the input $x$. I don't understand why the derivative can have one input variable while the regular function can have a different input variable. Why is that allowed?